# create a div tag and store into database and display in php, mysql and codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

What I am going to do is Im trying to insert a div tag into database then display it..

for example I'm going to store this code to database and display to my container

```
<div>
<p> This is the <b>paragraph</b> that i want to display </p>
</div>
```

I'm planning to build a website that the user can create a paragraph or change the color of the text without using any code. absolutely generated itself.. I don't know Where do I start first..

Comment: Start by writing some code?!

Comment: what do you mean? I want that code above to store into database, is that possible?

Comment: Ow in that case, yes it's possible

Comment: so can you give me an idea?

Comment: I'm begging you please. teach me how.

Comment: **SO is not a teaching portal** - We are not here to teach people how to program, you do that in your own time.

Comment: sorry  for that but i'm only asking on where do I start first not to teach me on entire coding.. by the way, i'm apologize for what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert html in table then use Editor like Tinymce or any other.